# How do I assign a jQuery object to a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have two autocomplete containers. Instead of writing code twice, I will use the same autocomplete call.

But in order to triger correct autocomplete (read: populate correct result list), I need to assign it to a variable. I've done this a long time ago, but I have forgotten how I did it.

So I have the following:

```
  autocomplete: function () {
    var autocompleteInput = null;
    var autocompleteResultList = null;

    $('.autocomplete').on("input", function (e) { // I have 2 of these
      autocompleteInput = $(this);  // This is the input i'm working with
      autocompleteResultList = autocompleteInput.closest('.autocomplete-result');
      resourcesData(autocompleteInput.val());
    }).on('focus', function (e) {
      autocompleteInput.val(''); //Cannot read property 'val' of null
    }).on('blur', function (e) {
      autocompleteResultList.removeClass('is-active');
    });
  }
```

My HTML x 2 (short version)

```
      <div class="autocomplete-wrapper">
        <input class="autocomplete" type="text" >
        <input class="resource-id" type="hidden">
        <div class="autocomplete-result"></div>
      </div>
```

I'm pretty sure it' some basic jQuery knowledge in regards of setting a variable = a jQuery object (`autocompleteInput = $(this);`) and how it all works that I've forgotten.

Any help appreciated :)

PS. I'm not using jQuery autocomplete - I've made my own.

Comment: In each event callback `this` is going to be the element that the event was triggered from, just use it, no need to assign it to a variable. Also it would be `autocompleteInput.val()` not `autocompleteInput.value` in the input event

Comment: In addition to what @PatrickEvans says, `focus` will happen before `input`. So you'd need to change at least the order of assignment (that's where the error comes from). The way you are assigning stuff is very error prone. It would also throw if a user focuses the input field and blurs it without any input.

Comment: @baao That might be, but chaining the way I've done works just fine.

Comment: I didn't say something about chaining...

Comment: What does `resourcesData` do? I would assume it gets the data to show in  `autocompleteResultList`, but that latter is no where provided nor assigned to.

Comment: @trincot Yes, it's my function for fetching data and populating the result list.

Comment: How does it know where to populate it? You don't provide it with `autocomplateResultList`....

Comment: I was hoping that `autocompleteInput.closest('.autocomplete-result')` would do the trick to locate the div after the input field.

Comment: That is a good intention, but does your function have access to that the `autocompleteInput` variable? Shouldn't you pass something like that to your function `resourcesData`? See my answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to abandon the variables that you share across the different event callbacks. But since they are easy to derive, just do that in each event handler itself.

Some things to note:

- The `closest` method only looks to parents, not to siblings, so use the `siblings` method instead (or if your structure is slightly different than in your question, maybe `.closest(".autocomplete-wrapper").find(".autocomplete-result")`).
- `resourcesData` is currently not provided with any information about where it should populate the data, so you should pass it an extra argument for it to know where to populate, and deal with that argument in that function.

Suggested code would then be:

```
autocomplete: function () {
    $('.autocomplete').on("input", function (e) {
        // extra argument
        resourcesData($(this).val(), $(this).siblings('.autocomplete-result'));
    }).on('focus', function (e) {
        $(this).val('');
    }).on('blur', function (e) {
        $(this).siblings('.autocomplete-result').removeClass('is-active');
    });
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was not sure which was doing what, so now I'm using `.parent().find()`. But I'll replace (and test) with `siblings`. And as Patrick Evans explained, I don't need to assign variables and just use `this`. Thanks for all the feedback guys :) I'm posting my complete solution so other can see the working solution.

Answer (score 0):

So after good help from Patric, Baao and Trincot (and others), I got it working. So just want to share my working solution just incase others are facing similar issues. It's probably not the most elegant solution, but it's working :)

```
let resources = {
  init: function () {
    this.searchResources();
  },

  searchResources: function () {
    var self = this;

    $('.autocomplete').on("input", function (e) {
      let term = $(this).val();
      if(term.length > 1){
        self.autocomplete($(this));
      }
    }).on('focus', function (e) {
      $(this).val('');
    }).on('blur', function (e) {
      $(this).closest('.autocomplete-result').removeClass('is-active');
    });
  },

  autocomplete: function(obj){
    let url = 'http://localhost.no:8080/resources%TERM';
    url = url.replace('%TERM', '/' + $(obj).val() );

    var resultList = $(obj).siblings('.autocomplete-result');
    let source = $('#autocomplete-list').html();
    let template = Handlebars.compile (source);

    $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: url,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(result) {
        let content = template({resources: result.data});
        $(resultList).html(content);

        $('.autocomplete-list-item').on('click', function (e) {
          $(obj).siblings('input.resource-id').val($(this).data('resource-id'));
          $(obj).val($(this).data('resource-name'));
          $(resultList).removeClass('is-active');
          console.log($(this).data('resource-id'));
          console.log($(this).data('resource-name'));
        });
      },
      error: function(err){console.log(err);}
    }).done(function () {
      var resultList = $(obj).siblings('.autocomplete-result');

      if(!$(resultList).hasClass('is-active')){
        $(resultList).addClass('is-active')
      }
    });
  }
};
```

One of my input fields looks like this:

```
      <div class="input-field column is-6 autocomplete-wrapper">
        <input id="autocomplete-owner" class="autocomplete" autocomplete="off" type="text" >
        <label for="autocomplete-owen">Prosjektleder</label>
        <input id="resource-id-owner" class="resource-id" type="hidden" name="resource-id-owner">
        <div class="autocomplete-result"></div>
      </div>
```